# Chat server and show user typing

Tags: php

I am working on a little test project to implement a chat server for a site I am working on. I have followed the guide from http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket and I've got it all pretty much working, I've also managed to amend it slightly so that you can send messages to individual users instead of globally to all online users.

What I am looking for now though whether using the implementation as shown in the tutorial above whether I can show that the user is currently typing.

I was thinking about looking for key events and just send a system message to the user and I can handle this in the client to show typing and then if after a second nothing else has come in hide it again, but this seems a bit inefficient and network.

Would my idea above be the only solution or is there a better implementation?

Answer (score 3):

It actually depends on your definition of "currently typing".

For me, that would be "there is some text in the input field".
This would require you to listen to `change` events on the input field and only send a message when the field turns from empty to non-empty or the other way round.
And, of course, the server would need to send a "stopped typing" message if the user disconnected.

However, if your definition is "user has touched a key in the last X milliseconds", then there is no other way but to constantly send messages.
Besides being more network-intensive, this option has the disadvantage of lags being shown as disconnects, possibly resulting in a shaky UI appearance.

Either way, I would listen for `change` on the input field, and not for actual key presses.

Comment: Thanks the first option does sound better, only sending the typing when the box isn't empty